# Make PHP login and show selected fields of SQL database

Tags: php, javascript, html

how to make php user login and after login show selected feilds of sql database in the web page

Comment: This is an extremely basic question, and you could find plenty of examples by using a search engine.

Comment: Please break your question into specific parts and give more information.  See http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: if you want some effort from us to answer this question, make an effort to outline/break it down properly with specific questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way for you to get started would be to use Basic Auth.  See http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Now, all that does is get you a username and password, but saves you the hassle from building a login form and dealing with sessions for the moment.  (Later on, investigate [sessions](http://us.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php).)

After you get that far, make a new question on Stack Overflow with your specific question for querying a database.  Be sure to include what DB server you are using, your DB schema, and what you have tried thus far.